# Xuggler: error using to convert video from .mp4 to .webm

Tags: xuggler

I got following error while using Xuggler to convert a video from mp4 to webm

```
3:02:27,344 ERROR [status_jsp:665] java.lang.RuntimeException: could not open stream com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream@1423372160[index:0;id:0;streamcoder:com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder@1423442272[codec=com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec@1423293632[type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO;id=CODEC_ID_VORBIS;name=libvorbis;];time base=1/44100;frame rate=0/0;sample rate=44100;channels=2;];framerate:0/0;timebase:1/90000;direction:OUTBOUND;]: Operation not permitted
java.lang.RuntimeException: could not open stream com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream@1423372160[index:0;id:0;streamcoder:com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder@1423442272[codec=com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec@1423293632[type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO;id=CODEC_ID_VORBIS;name=libvorbis;];time base=1/44100;frame rate=0/0;sample rate=44100;channels=2;];framerate:0/0;timebase:1/90000;direction:OUTBOUND;]: Operation not permitted
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.openStream(MediaWriter.java:1192)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.getStream(MediaWriter.java:1052)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeAudio(MediaWriter.java:830)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.onAudioSamples(MediaWriter.java:1441)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.AMediaToolMixin.onAudioSamples(AMediaToolMixin.java:89)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.dispatchAudioSamples(MediaReader.java:628)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.decodeAudio(MediaReader.java:555)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket(MediaReader.java:469)
    at com.test.xuggler.Test.processAction(Test.java:26)
```

Comment: I get the same error. Did you find a solution?